# Group related controls on ToolStrip so they are always visible together

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I have an application that has a tool strip with related controls set apart by ToolStripSeparaters. It looks something like this:

[image: Scenario width adequate screen width. Related controls shown together.]

However, when the window size shrinks, some of the controls get moved to a little drop-down section. Unfortunately, this can split related controls, for example in the screenshot below, the "Filter by ID" label, the associated textbox for the ID, and "Clear Filter" button are no longer shown together.

[image: Narrower window with related controls split apart]

If controls have to be moved to the drop-down, I'd prefer to have related controls move together. Is there a way to group related controls together on a ToolStrip? Or perhaps a better way of dealing with this sort of scenario?

---

I tried using the `LayoutCompleted` event move all of the controls to the overflow area if any of them are in the overflow.

```
private void toolStrip1_LayoutCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var filterGroup = new List<ToolStripItem> { lblFilter, txtFilter, btnClearFilter };
  if (filterGroup.Any(x => x.IsOnOverflow))
  {
    filterGroup.ForEach(x => x.Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.Always);
  }
}
```

This seems to work fine, but I haven't found a good way to show them again when the window size is increased. I tried both the `Resize` and `Layout` events of the ToolStrip with the following code:

```
var filterGroup = new List<ToolStripItem> { lblFilter, txtFilter, btnClearFilter };
filterGroup.ForEach(x => x.Overflow = ToolStripItemOverflow.AsNeeded);
```

Comment: You've presumably tried hooking the `ToolStrip`'s `LayoutCompleted` event? If so, please show that, and show what you tried doing in there and explain why it doesn't meet your need.

Comment: @ClickRick See edit.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `ToolStripControlHost` to group a `winforms` `TextBox` and `Label`. E.g.

```
public class ToolStripLabelTextBox : ToolStripControlHost {

    public Label Label { get; private set; }
    public TextBox TextBox { get; private set; }

    public ToolStripLabelTextBox(String labelText) : base(new FlowLayoutPanel { FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight, WrapContents = false, AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink, Padding = Padding.Empty, Margin = Padding.Empty }) {
        Label = new Label { Text = labelText, AutoSize = true, Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom, TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter };
        TextBox = new TextBox();

        FlowLayoutPanel panel = (FlowLayoutPanel) Control;
        panel.Controls.Add(Label);
        panel.Controls.Add(TextBox);
    }
}
```

Two other options are:

1. Implement a `LayoutEngine` that does the grouping you want.
2. Implement a composite `ToolStripItem` that displays a label and text box. You can use the `ToolStripRadioButtonMenuItem` as an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms404318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx